# Best method to include an external js with the current HTTP protocol

Tags: javascript

What's the cleanest method to include an external javascript using the current HTTP protocol type to avoid SSL partial security issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script src="//whatever-domain.com/path/to/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Very clean, wondering why google analytics and big websites use some complex syntaxes to detect HTTPs and then include the script.. is that cross browser?

Comment: I believe it's cross-browser -- it's easy enough to test. My guess for most people is that they didn't know, but felt clever doing it in JS. Or maybe there really is a good reason not to use this. If there is one, I don't know about it yet.

Comment: It solves my problem of using google maps, but does this work if the domain you are interacting with doesn't support both http and https?

Comment: @Hoffmann: No. As mentioned by jnpcl below, you need to know that the site will work with both SSL and non-SSL requests.

Answer (score 3):

Dropping the scheme, but leaving the double slash will use the current scheme

```
//www.example.com/foo/bar.js
```

Comment: Just make sure that the external server supports SSL connections first. :)